# Beginner bash scripting

Tags: bash

I want to break down a file that has multiple lines that follow this style:

```
e-mail;year/month/date;groups;sharedFolder
```

An example line from file:

```
alan.turing@cam.ac.uk;1912/06/23;visitor;/visitorData
```

Essentially I want to break each line up into four arrays that can be accessed later on in a loop to create a new user for each line.

- I have declared the arrays already have a file saved as variable 'filename'
- Usernames need to be the first three letters of the surname and the first three letters of the first name.
- Passwords need to be the users birthdate as day/month/year.

So far this is what I have. Am I on the right track? Are there places I have gone wrong or could improve on?

```
#reads file and saves into appropriate arrays
while read -r line
do
  IFS = $';' read -r -a array <<< "$line"

  mailArray += "$(array[0])"
  dateArray += "$(array[1])"
  groupArray += "$(array[2])"
  folderArray += "$(array[3])"
done < $filename


#create usernames from emails
for i in "$(mailArray[@])"
do
  IFS=$'.' read -r -a array <<< "$i"

  part1 = ${array[0]:0:3}
  part2 = ${array[1]:0:3}

  user = $part2
  user .= $part1

  userArray += ("$user")
done


#create passwords from birthdates
for i in "$(dateArray[@])"
do
  IFS=$'/' read -r -a array <<< "$i"

  password = $part3
  password .= $part2
  password .= $part1

  passArray += ("$password")
done
```

Comment: Any reason for using arrays and storing them in files? why not just process one line as it's read ?

Comment: I think this question might get better, and more, answers in [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if arrays are required here, and if you just want to create username, password from the lines in the desired format, please see below:

```
# Sample Input Data:

bash$> cat d
alan.turing@cam.ac.uk;1912/06/23;visitor;/visitorData
rob.zombie@cam.ac.uk;1966/06/23;metalhead;/metaldata
donald.trump@stupid.com;1900/00/00;idiot;/idiotique
bash$>

# Sample Output from script:

bash$> ./dank.sh "d"

        After processing the line [alan.turing@cam.ac.uk;1912/06/23;visitor;/visitorData], we have the following parameters extracted:

        Name:           alan
        Surname:        turing
        Birthdate:      1912/06/23
        username:       alatur
        Password:       1912/06/23



        After processing the line [rob.zombie@cam.ac.uk;1966/06/23;metalhead;/metaldata], we have the following parameters extracted:

        Name:           rob
        Surname:        zombie
        Birthdate:      1966/06/23
        username:       robzom
        Password:       1966/06/23



        After processing the line [donald.trump@stupid.com;1900/00/00;idiot;/idiotique], we have the following parameters extracted:

        Name:           donald
        Surname:        trump
        Birthdate:      1900/00/00
        username:       dontru
        Password:       1900/00/00
```

Now the script, which does this operation.

```
# Script.

bash$> cat dank.sh
#!/bin/bash


cat "$1" | while read line
do
        name=`echo $line | sed 's/^\(.*\)\..*\@.*$/\1/g'`
        surname=`echo $line | sed 's/^.*\.\(.*\)\@.*$/\1/g'`
        bdate=`echo $line | sed 's/^.*;\(.*\);.*;.*$/\1/g'`

        temp1=`echo $name | sed 's/^\(...\).*$/\1/g'`
        temp2=`echo $surname | sed 's/^\(...\).*$/\1/g'`

        uname="${temp1}${temp2}"

        echo "
        After processing the line [$line], we have the following parameters extracted:

        Name:           $name
        Surname:        $surname
        Birthdate:      $bdate
        username:       $uname
        Password:       $bdate

        "
done
bash$>
```

Basically, i am just running couple of sed commands to extract what is useful and required, and storing them in variables and then one could use them anyways they want to. You could redirect them to a file if you want or print out a pipe separated output.. upto you.

Let me know..